# Splinter: How to pass argument to execute_script?

Tags: javascript, python, splinter

I need to execute a javascript function on the page, by passing it an array of strings. I want to avoid having to call `browser.execute_script` number of times.

```
list_of_strings = ['a','b','c']

#js code runs through all the strings
result = browser.execute_script("function findTexts(textList){//code here}", list_of_strings)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump python list to `JSON` and use *string formatting*:

```
import json

json_array = json.dumps(list_of_strings)
result = browser.execute_script("function findTexts(%s){//code here}" % json_array)
```

Here's what js code does it produce:

```
>>> import json
>>> list_of_strings = ['a','b','c']
>>> json_array = json.dumps(list_of_strings)
>>> "function findTexts(%s){//code here}" % json_array
'function findTexts(["a", "b", "c"]){//code here}'
```

Comment: in the javascript code, how would I iterate through the list? what if the number of items in the list is unpredictable?

Comment: @KJW just use a basic javascript loop, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript.

Comment: I ended up doing this `browser.evaluate_script("findTexts(%s);function findTexts(list){//do something with list array}");` turns out `evaluate_script` returns the results.